# reservation without any time overlap

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing php script which checks and allocates  available free slot to reserve a certain machine. The table looks like this:

```
    machine      start_time    duration(mins)
      1             11:00       30 
      1             12:00       40
      1             13:00       30
      1             14:00       40
      2             11:00       10
      2             12:10       30
      2             13:00       10
```

when the user gives start time the system should automatically assign machine and max possible duration the user can use.  No partial nor total overlap on the same machine.

Here is part of the script I tried:

```
    $time = $_POST['starttime'];
    $duration = $_POST['duration'];

    $query1 = "SELECT machine_id FROM machinetable";
    $res1 = mysql_query($query1$query1,$conn);

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1)) {
        $y = $row1['machine_id'];
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM tableabove where machine_id = '$y' Order By start_time DESC";

        $result = mysql_query($qry,$conn);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         // WHAT SHALL I ADD HERE.....JUST SOME HINT OR ANOTHER MEANS THAT HELPS
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some examples to clarify what your rules are.

Comment: 1. See JOIN. 2. See 1.

Comment: forexample if the user wants to use the machine beginning from 11:40....the system should give him machine two , because the duration the user can use is maximum (30 min) compared to 20 mins when its machine 1. thats what I wanted

Comment: you have `$duration = $_POST['duration'];` Does this mean that you know from start how much time you need? Or do you just need as much as possible?

Comment: $duration will be reset according to available minimum and maximum duration , the system suggests

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select machine_id, duration
from table t
where starttime = USERSTARTTIME
order by duration desc
limit 1;
```

This returns the machine and duration.  Your php code can then do the "reservation".

EDIT:

Try this instead:

```
select machine_id, duration - timediff(USERSTARTTIME, starttime) as durationForUser
from table t
where timediff(USERSTARTTIME, starttime) between 0 and duration
order by duration - timediff(USERSTARTTIME, starttime) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: No, forexample if the user wants to use the machine beginning from 11:40....the system should give him machine two , because the duration the user can use is  maximum (30 min)  compared to 20 mins when its machine 1. thats what I wanted